# How to debug the Null Safety default value type error on double question mark '??'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I recently run into some strange behavior when using double question mark.
Here is the example code:

```
void main() {
  String strA;
  String strB;

  print('start');
  strB = strA ?? 5; // wrong use of default value type. It should be a String here.
  print('end');
}
```

The program never run to the end and **even not throwing out any error message**.

Is the behavior expected?

Comment: First ,you should make your `strA` nullable using `String? strA`. Regardless, `A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'`. The program even won't compile.

Comment: Actually it can compile without any error on my computer (tried on Android Studio and DartPad), only throw error message until runtime.

Comment: The main problem was happen when I tried to learn riverpod package from it's example(Todo https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/examples/todos), while I did a very dump mistake that write `id = id ?? _uuid.v4();` to `id = id ?? _uuid.v4;`. It took me a while debugging because it just pass this line without throwing any error message.

Comment: So I make a small reproducible code here. Thanks for the mysterious power, this simple example works as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you're running this code?

When I run it, I get this output:

```
▶ dart test.dart
start
Unhandled exception:
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
#0      main (file:///Users/renato/programming/projects/test.dart:6:3)
```

As I expected.

What Dart version are you using (run `dart --version`)? Make sure you have an up-to-date version like `2.10`.

If you still have issues, you might have a local `analysis_options.yaml` file which overrides the Dart compiler checks to be more lenient, in which case it might not check the types (I am not sure which option would enable this, but I suppose it's possible).

Check how analysis options work [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options).

I suggest you always enable "strong mode" by adding this to your analysis options file:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

By the way, if you want to try the new Dart NNBD (Not-Null-By-Default) experimental feature, you need to use the Dart dev channel releases and run your program with `dart --enable-experiment=non-nullable file.dart`.

To learn how to enable NNBD, check the [null-safety tech preview 2](https://medium.com/flutter/null-safety-flutter-tech-preview-cb5c98aba187) blog post about it.

Comment: Strange thing that it did happen this morning in my Android Studio (Dart 2.11.0-213.1.beta (beta)) and DartPad online (Based on Flutter 1.23.0-18.1.pre Dart SDK 2.10.3). It now all print out the error message. Thank you.